# R studio was forced to restart

Tags: r, xgboost, vip

Anyone can explain what does this mean? I ran xgboost with tree model, it took me four hours to finish up tuning all the parameters. When i tried to use vip function to show the important variables, but R studio was forced to restart, so my work was gone. The author of this method told me to check if it is RAM problem. She said "If the problem is RAM, you might want to do something like computing that in a fresh session with the saved model or something". I am not sure what does it mean?

Comment: Probably saving the model like this - https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-package/xgboostPresentation.html#save-and-load-models

Comment: If your computer has just barely enough RAM to be able to do this calculation, then having extraneous variables in your environment can be just enough to push it over the edge. While small variables are typically not a problem, larger ones might need to be pruned. `ls.objects(order.by="Size", decreasing=TRUE, head=TRUE, n=10)` will give you the 10 largest objects in your current environment, where `Kb` or `bytes` are easy, but `Mb` or larger might need some manual intervention.